# How to manage two efi parition for two different installations of ubuntu?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, lubuntu

Recently my hard drive I gave me some bad sector. Just a few days ago there was a corruption of data. So it seems my hard drive is reaching the end of its life.

So one option was to buy a new hard disk but I will replace the laptop in like next 5-6 months so I didn't want to add expense. So I installed Ubuntu on an external hard drive.When I installed it, external Ubuntu changed the EFI partition of the internal hard drive. Now I need to connect the external hard drive to boot.

I want to separate both EFI partitions. I want an EFI partition that can open internal hard drive ubuntu without an external drive as well as I want to boot in external if the internal fails. So I want two different EFI one on internal and one on external.

I tried running update-grub from internal ubuntu. It showed me that it can detect windows from internal as well as ubuntu from external. But it doesn't modify the EFI partition.
Also, how do I configure a separate EFI partition to the external drive? I already created 200MB of EFI fat32 partition in an external drive. I copied the entire EFI from internal to external. I tested if it boots or not from the custom entry I created in bios. So now I want to know how to boot internal grub from the internal hard drive and what changes other than the EFI path in /etc/default/grub I need to make in external to get everything working.

Comment: Look at the internal disk's EFI partition /EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg and change the disk references and UUID (back) to the internal disks' Ubuntu root.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thank you. It worked. Also, can I now boot in this external hard drive without internal. I think yes but just want to confirm if there is still some dependency on an internal hard drive.

Comment: You may answer your own question, after a few days, mark it as solved, and gain a few points for yourself, while helping others with a solution that worked for you.

Comment: @ubfan1 I will appreciate it if you can write the answer. I will approve it. You helped me a lot. If nothing more than you at least deserve some reputation points. I will accept the answer. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launchpad bug #1396379 (During installation user's input for location of bootloadder is ignored and first EFI found is used), is the cause of these sorts of problems.  Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" on the bug if you ever install to a second disk. Outside the installer, grub works fine, and may be used with appropriate options to specify where you install it.

The result of installation to a second disk is that the EFI of the first disk is updated and still boots grub, but now grub's additional files are located on the second disk.  This works as long as the second disk is attached. Without the second disk attached, grub cannot find the files it needs to continue booting.  Copying the first disk's EFI file to the second disk's EFI will result in a working boot for the second disk. Select/put the disk as first in the boot order to boot.

The fix for the first EFI is to edit the EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg file (it's only a few lines) to change the disk/partition references back to the the first disk, and use the UUID (provided by running sudo blkid in a terminal) for the Ubuntu on the first disk.  This change allows grub to boot off the first disk.  The only other change you (might) need is to restore the Windows bootloader to the default for the device.  The file /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi was originally the Windows bootloader, but it probably got renamed to /EFI/Boot/bckbootx64.efi (or maybe bootx64.efi.bup). Check the size of the Windows bootloader in /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi to ensure bckbootloader.efi is really the Windows bootloader. Then just copy it (or /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi) back to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Put the device or the /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi second in the boot order, so if the second disk is not attached, it will boot the second entry.